# Omitting a verb at the end of a sentence to avoid repetition

Tags: ellipsis

> Children’s endeavor and growth are valuable just like their success and it is not only successes that are scored, but also efforts and progress [are also scored].

Is it correct to omit the the last part inside brackets, given the fact that the verb "scored" is already used in the sentence?

Comment: Leve it out, it's fine.

Comment: For a nicer sentence, I would recommend "...but so are efforts and progress."

Comment: Also "...but also ***their*** efforts and progress."

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct - and reads much more naturally.

I would put a comma after the first "success" like this, and insert "their" as suggested by @user3169:

> Children’s endeavor and growth are valuable just like their success, and it is not only successes that are scored, but also *their* efforts and progress.

Note that the use of the word "endeavor" here is quite correct, but it is unusual.

Comment: I think you want also **before** *their*?